# How to register multiple message handlers in aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, aiogram, telebot

I'm trying to make multiple different message handlers, **is this an acceptable way to register multiple ones?**:

```py
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from settings import BOT_TOKEN


async def start_handler(event: types.Message):
    await event.answer(
        f"Hello, {event.from_user.get_mention(as_html=True)} !",
        parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML,
    )

async def echo_answer(event: types.Message):
    await event.answer(event.text, parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML
    )


async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
    try:
        disp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
        disp.register_message_handler(start_handler, commands={"start", "restart"})
        disp.register_message_handler(echo_answer, lambda msg: msg.text)
        await disp.start_polling()
    finally:
        await bot.close()

asyncio.run(main())
```

my settings.py file contains

```py
import os

BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
if not BOT_TOKEN:
    print('You have forgot to set BOT_TOKEN')
    BOT_TOKEN = 'missing'
    quit()
```

This code runs, and sends echo responses to any message and replies with Hello, @username ! for start and restart commands.
to reproduce one must have a bot and have a BOT_TOKEN in the environmental variables before running the code.

I tried this code, described above, looked ad https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/index.html documentation and modified example on the source code page https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram#poll-botapi-for-updates-and-process-updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem, so I made little dive into source code of aiogram.

Handlers in `Dispatcher` instance held in multiple properties.

- `message_handlers`
- `edited_message_handlers`
- `channel_post_handlers`
- and *etc* (you can view full list of them in autocomplete of your IDE or at [source code page](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py#L67))

Every handler is instance of `Handler` class, so they have `once` property, that shows, can mulltiple handlers be called on one message

So in your case, you should set `message_handlers.once` to `False`

```py
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN)
    try:
        disp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)
        disp.message_handlers.once = False 
        disp.register_message_handler(start_handler, commands={"start", "restart"})
        disp.register_message_handler(echo_answer, lambda msg: msg.text)
        await disp.start_polling()
    finally:
        await bot.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

**IF YOU ARE USING AIOGRAM 3.+ SKIP THIS (Solution for legacy)**

so first you need a variable with handlers you need to register.
since dispatcher.register takes in callable, then *filters and then keywords you've
got to be percise with what you will pass in.

How I would do it (example):

```
bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot)
register_handlers = [
    
    (help_handler, (filters.CommandHelp()), {"state": "*"}),
    # Example of handler with tuple of filters (only 1 here)

    (start_handler, {"commands": ["start"], "state": "*"}),
    # Example of handler with no filters, but keywords
]
for handler in register_handlers:
    if isinstance(handler[1], dict):
        dispatcher.register(handler[0], **handler[1])
    else:
        dispatcher.register(handler[0], *handler[1], **handler[2])
```

So the tirck is to always pass some keywords as a dict into register_handlers.

**If you are aiogram creator or contributor - please read this**

Please make *filters in dispatcher.register function a keyword, that takes in iterable of filters. This will ease registering multiple handlers dramatically. Thank you.

Comment: aiogram is open source, you can create a pull request to do this in github https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram

Comment: Ima noob, so I don't think I should do this. Plus Aiogram 3.1 released. Brand new stuff

Comment: if it's still relevant maybe you could ask for advice in https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/discussions.  making helpful contributions is a great way to learn!